# Toolbar alignment in MFC application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, mfc

I am new to MFC development, learning the basics.  I want to create a sample MFC application containing 8 toolbars, I want them to appear as follows :

T1-T2-T3-T4

T5-T6-T7-T8

But, they always appear as follows :

T1-T2-T3-T4-T5-T6-T7-T8

How to bring the toolbar in to multiple lines? I have no idea how to achieve this.

What I have done so far for docking toolbar is given below :

```
DockPane(&m_wndToolBar);
DockPane(&tb1);
DockPane(&tb2);
DockPane(&tb3);
DockPaneLeftOf(&tb1, &m_wndToolBar);
DockPaneLeftOf(&m_wndToolBar, &tb2);
DockPaneLeftOf(&tb2, &tb3);
DockPane(&tb4);
DockPane(&tb6);
DockPane(&tb7);
DockPane(&tb8);
DockPane(&tb9);
DockPaneLeftOf(&tb6, &tb4);
DockPaneLeftOf(&tb7, &tb6);
DockPaneLeftOf(&tb8, &tb7);
DockPaneLeftOf(&tb9, &tb8);
```

Comment: Sounds like you need a ReBar that can multiple rows.

Answer (score 1):

Not tested but can you try:

`DockPane(&tb4);
DockPaneLeftOf(&tb3,&tb4);
DockPaneLeftOf(&tb2,&tb3);
DockPaneLeftOf(&tb1,&tb2);
DockPane(&tb8);
DockPaneLeftOf(&tb7,&tb8);
DockPaneLeftOf(&tb6,&tb7);
DockPaneLeftOf(&tb5,&tb6);`

Comment: i just try out your suggestion, when i build my application the output was still on single row but with only the first toolbars i mean "tb1,tb2,tb3,tb4"